# How to use 2 gridview cell values column to build a hyper link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview. I need to build a hyperlink in one column with the value from a different one and its own value. So for example the URL would be something.com/column1value/column2value.

I have the System and theregion hyperlinked via a TemplateField in there respective column. It is in column 2 that i want to build the url based on the value in column1

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL" Class='table table-hover' BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="White" GridLines="None" UseAccessibleHeader="False" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EnableTheming="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="System" SortExpression="System">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("System") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("System", "http://evemaps.dotlan.net/system/{0}/") %>' Target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("System", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Region", "http://evemaps.dotlan.net/Map/{0}/") %>' Target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("Region", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EvE Time" SortExpression="EvE Time">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[EvE Time]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="EvETimeLB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[EvE Time]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What about if the text has spaces e.g "manchester city" but i want to replace the spaces in the hyperlink (not the text) with underscores

Comment: Then do this: `string.Format("something.com/{0}/{1}", Eval("column1").ToString().Replace(" ", "_"), Eval("column2").ToString().Replace(" ", "_"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Eval` is not restricted to the column you are using it in. You can use all the columns in an ItemTemplate.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" 
   NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("something.com/{0}/{1}", Eval("column1"), Eval("column2")) %>' 
   Text='<%# string.Format("something.com/{0}/{1}", Eval("column1"), Eval("column2")) %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```